# rsyslog: how to bind rulesets to unix sockets (imuxsock)

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using the [imuxsock module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imuxsock.html) to listen to additional local log sockets (i.e., with the `$AddUnixListenSocket` directive).

After reading the awesome http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/multi_ruleset.html page, I'm interested in binding separate rulesets to each socket. That page gives the example of binding a ruleset to a particular tcp port (i.e., using the imtcp module & it's `$InputTCPServerBindRuleset` directive), but according to that page:

> Note that the input module must support binding to non-standard
>   rulesets, so the functionality may not be available with all inputs.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do the same with imuxsock. Is the feature there, but undocumented? Or is there some *other* way to accomplish the same (applying *X* rules to messages from *X* socket and *Y* rules to messages from *Y* socket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY.

[imuxsock: add ruleset support](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/765)

Done in rsyslog v8.17. Now to figure out if it works ...

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, and I couldn't find it. And I assume it's just not supported. Here's a comment from the source code.

> /* we do not use this, because we do not bind to a ruleset so far  *
>   enable when this is changed: #include "im-helper.h" */ /* must be
>   included AFTER the type definitions! */

I assume it can be implemented. You can either contribute a patch or pay the guys at Adiscon to do it.